# Role hierarchical vs action based permission system

Tags: permissions, architecture, software-design

I have a web software application where I have users with roles in a hierarchy like
`Organization -> Team -> project -> folder`, each level admin has access to all levels under it, and some other custom permissions for each user. For each level I keep SQL join table with columns like
 `team_id, user_id, role, permissions`

I wonder if it is worth converting this hierarchical system to flat action based permission for each user. Having additional database or tables keeping all actions for each user. Which one is better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Flattening for performance will make it perform better, but require a lot of duplication of data in order to specify all the various permissions.

The best-of-both is to have the hierarchical or RBAC representation be the desired state and translate that into a read-only flattened view on update.  This can take a LOT of space though, depending on how fine-grained your permissions get (permissions-per-row can explode this to an unreasonable degree)